# Boxing Conversion or Identity Conversion?

Tags: c#, .net, generics, boxing

I stumbled upon this problem when I was reading through the 3rd edition of **C# in Depth**. The book has the following in Table 3.2 in P.74.

> `class Sample<T> where T : IComparable<T`> | *Valid*: `Sample<int>` (boxing conversion), *Invalid*: `Sample<FileInfo>`

Let's consider the following.

```
using System;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Sample<int> s1 = new Sample<int>();                 // ---(1.1)
        Sample<object> s2 = new Sample<object>();           // ---(1.2)
        Sample<OtherSample> s3 = new Sample<OtherSample>(); // ---(1.3)
        s1.Print();
        s2.Print();
    }
}

public class Sample<T> where T : IComparable<T> {
    public void Print() {
        Console.WriteLine(this);
    }
}

public class OtherSample : IComparableExtended<OtherSample> {
    public int CompareTo(OtherSample obj) {
        return 0;
    }
}

public interface IComparableExtended<T> : IComparable<T> {}
```

Obviously, 1.2 is blatantly wrong, as there is no implicit reference conversion from `object` to `System.IComparable<object>`. I really don't have a problem with 1.1 also, except that the book says it is *Boxing Conversion*. Now, `int` is actually an alias for `Int32` struct, which inherits through the hierarchy `Object->ValueType->Int32`. This implements the interface `System.IComparable<T>` as `IComparable<Int32>`, which is why 1.1 is correct. As I understood, what `where T : IComparable<T>` means is that **T should be something that implements IComparable**. I figured that `Int32` implements this interface and hence satisfying the type constraint for `Sample<T>`. In that sense, is this really Boxing Conversion as the book suggests? Or is this Identity Conversion?

1.3 makes this even more confusing and contradicting with what is in the book. When `public class Sample<T> where T : IComparable<T>` signature is changed to `public class Sample<T> where T : IComparableExtended<T>`, even 1.1 becomes a compile time error.

So my question is, Can 1.1 really be considered as boxing conversion? Or else my entire idea on boxing, and generic type conversions is wrong?

Comment: It's impossible to understand your question fully without knowing what text in the book you're actually asking about. Please fix your question so that you've included the _verbatim_ citation(s) from the book that your question is based on.

Comment: I don't understand what's your problem with 1.3, though I haven't read the book so I don't know what it states about it. IMHO and without testing, it should be fine since the `OtherSample` implements an interface that inherits `IComparable<T>` which means it is implementing the `IComparable<T>` too.

Comment: " When public class Sample<T> where T : IComparable<T> signature is changed to public class Sample<T> where T : IComparableExtended<T>, even 1.1 becomes a compile time error." -- well, what did you expect? `int` does not implement `IComparableExtended<int>`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a boxing conversion.

A quick look at the documentation will get you to the [Boxing and Unboxing (C# Programming Guide)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/types/boxing-and-unboxing) page, that starts with the following text:

> Boxing is the process of converting a value type to the type object **or to any interface type implemented by this value type.**

(emphasis mine)

Since `Sample<T>` is defined with a generic constraint on an interface, it will box any struct that implements this interface when initialized with it.

Comment: The sentence that follows your excerpt (*When the common language runtime (CLR) boxes a value type, it wraps the value inside a System.Object instance and stores it on the managed heap*) mislead me I think. Thanks for your clarification. It adds up now..